# it doesn't show me the percentage of progress bar in output nor does it abort the upload. I think $form is not working

Tags: php, jquery

This is my `index.php` file with the `server.php` file in which it doesn't show me the percentage of progress bar in output nor does it abort the upload. I think $form is not working but I don't know the reason behind it. Can someone please help me out. I think my code is correct but still its not working properly.

image.php file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title> File Upload </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Uploader</h1>
        <hr>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm upload" type="submit"> Upload </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm cancel"> Cancel </button>
            <br>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" " style=" width:0%"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm upload" type="submit"> Upload </button>
            <button class="btn  btn-danger btn-sm cancel"> Cancel </button>
            <br>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" " style=" width:0%"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm  upload" type="submit"> Upload </button>
            <button class="btn  btn-danger btn-sm cancel"> Cancel </button>
            <br>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" " style=" width:0%"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $form = $(this);

            uploadImage($form);
        });

        function uploadImage($form) {

            $form.find('.progress-bar').removeClass('progress-bar-success').removeClass('progress-bar-danger');

            var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //progress event...
            request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {

                var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);

                $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
            });
            request.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
                $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('upload completed....');
            })
            console.log(formdata);
            request.open('post', 'server.php');
            request.send(formdata);

            $form.on('click', '.cancel', function() {
                request.abort();
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

server.php:

```php
<?php 
  $tmp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];

  move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'upload_folder/'. $filename); ?>
```

Comment: Can you format your code properly?

Comment: Please format the code properly so other users can understand it without having a headache.

Comment: i tried your code and its working perfectly, what error you are getting? it shows the progress bar and also uploaded the image on my side.

Comment: You have too much `"` in `role="progressbar" " style=" width:0%"`

Comment: check that `upload_folder/` exists and it has the permissions.